# Pytorch: proper way to compute gradients of sub-matrix

Tags: python, pytorch

I would like to calculate the gradient on a sub-matrix. Following snippets demonstrate my use case:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

A = torch.rand((3, 5), requires_grad=True)
target = torch.zeros((3, 5), requires_grad=True)
loss = nn.functional.mse_loss(A, target)

grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, A)[0]
print(f'full grad shape = {grad.shape}')

grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, A[:1, :])[0]
print(f'grad shape = {grad.shape}')
```

I can successfully calculate the gradients of loss w.r.t the matrix A. However, it fails with sub-matrix:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 226, in grad
    return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior.
```

My question is: how can I compute the gradient of sub-matrix?

Cross-post: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/gradients-of-sub-matrix/131608

Answer (score 0):

The MSE loss is a point-wise operator `f: x, y -> (x - y)²`, followed by an average of all tensor elements. You can get the un-reduced gradient expression by using the [`mse_loss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.mse_loss.html) `reduction` option and supplying `grad_outputs` on the `torch.autograd.grad` call. This effectively returns the same result.

- Reduced (averaged loss terms):

  ```
  >>> loss = F.mse_loss(A, target)
  >>> torch.autograd.grad(loss, A)
  (tensor([[0.1007, 0.0165, 0.0987, 0.0695, 0.0396],
           [0.1078, 0.0899, 0.0123, 0.0946, 0.0002],
           [0.0995, 0.1330, 0.1016, 0.0526, 0.1260]]),)
  ```
- Non reduced (non averaged loss terms):

  ```
  >>> loss = F.mse_loss(A, target, reduction='none')
  >>> grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, A, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(A))
  (tensor([[1.5112, 0.2482, 1.4800, 1.0422, 0.5942],
           [1.6166, 1.3482, 0.1850, 1.4184, 0.0028],
           [1.4926, 1.9952, 1.5236, 0.7886, 1.8894]]),)
  ```

So in your case `torch.autograd.grad(loss, A[:1])` would either correspond to one of the two results:

- The following slice of `grad[0]`, if you want the 'absolute' contribution of `A[1:]` towards the final loss result:

  ```
  >>> grad[0][1:]
  tensor([[1.5112, 0.2482, 1.4800, 1.0422, 0.5942]])
  ```
- Or, if you want to compute the average contribution based on that slice:

  ```
  >>> g0 = grad[0]
  >>> g0 / g0.numel() * g0[:1].numel() 
  tensor([[0.5037, 0.0827, 0.4933, 0.3474, 0.1981]])
  ```